# Argsort a 2D array by its 2D coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array, how to argsort its elements and obtain a list of the coordinates of the array elements from the lowest to highest.

For example, given:

```
1 5
2 3
```

We get:

```
[[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1].
```

Could we generalize it to `n` dimensional arrays?

Comment: assuming you have an N dimensional numpy array `A` you can do `np.argsort(A, None).reshape(A.shape)`

Answer (score 0):

For 2D the precise answer is:

```
A_2d_argsort = np.argsort(A, None)
ver = np.floor(A_2d_argsort // A.shape[1])
hor = A_2d_argsort % A.shape[1]

np.stack([ver,hor]).transpose()
```